# Python applying a method to elements pairs from two large lists take long time to process

Tags: python, list, pairwise

I have two lists containing string - The size of both lists is often 100,000 or even more.

I also have a method that takes two strings and measure their similarity distance. I have tried nested loops such as

```
Results=[]
for i in list_1:
   for j in list_2:
      Results.append( (i, j, edit_distance(i, j)) )
```

The problem is that this code takes a very long time to process due to the high number of comparisons. I have also tried zip() method, but it still takes a long time. Is there a way to make this comparison faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loops are not your problem. Calling `edit_distance` for each pair of strings is consuming almost all of your run time, so that's where you should first look to increase performance.

From what you've posted, the best improvement you could make would be to turn your loop into a generator to reduce the cost of generating a 100,000x100,000 element list:

```py
import itertools

def edit_distances(list1, list2):
    for i, j in itertools.product(list1, list2):
        yield (i, j, edit_distance(i, j))
```

Comment: Maybe import itertools outside the function?

Answer (score 0):

As `Woodford` already suggested, you can likely do much better with a generator -- **if** you need to access these figures only once through some sort of iteration.  If you need to index or reference them multiple times, or in some other order, then you'll need your full table.

It's possible that much of your time is wasted in enlarging a list of 10^10 elements, one element at a time.  Also, if this is a well-behaved distance function, then you know that f(i, j) == f(j, i), and that f(i, i) == 0, so you can cut your computation time by slightly more than half if you avoid redundant computations.

- If i == j, fill in 0, without calling the function.
- Memoize your function: if i > j, grab the stored value for `f(j, i)` instead of recomputing.
- Build the list with a comprehension, instead of 10^10 `append` operations.

  results = [0 if i == j
  else stored[(j_str, i_str)] if i > j
  else edit_distance(i_str, j_str)
  for i, i_str in list_1
  for j, j_str in list_2
  ]

This assumes that `edit_distance` is responsible to update the memory `stored`.  You can find details in any tutorial on memoization (and most references on dynamic programming).